# How to change a value to missing

Tags: julia, missing-data

I seem to be unable to change a value to missing in Julia version 0.6.4 (I believe it was allowed before 0.6).

Example code:

```
using Dataframes
x = zeros(5)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
x[3] = missing
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Missings.Missing to an     
object of type Float64
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Stacktrace:
[1] setindex!(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Missings.Missing, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:583
```

In this setting I am trying to encode certain indicies as missing values for an analysis. Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: Are you going to use a `Dataframe`? `Dataframes` has easy `missing` values support. After you add your data to the `Dataframe`, it's easy to just assign `missing` values then.

Comment: If you think I have satisfactorily answered the question, then it is a good idea to mark it answered by clicking the tick mark next to my response. If you feel the answer is unsatisfactory then please leave a comment on it and I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`missing` in Julia is of its own type:

```
julia> typeof(missing)
Missings.Missing
```

In your case, it is particularly important to note that:

```
julia> Missing <: Float64
false
```

That is, `Missing` is not a subtype of `Float64`. Now, note that:

```
julia> typeof(zeros(5))
Array{Float64,1}
```

So you construct `x`, an array that should *only* contain `Float64`. Since `missing` is not a subtype of `Float64`, when you try to change one of the elements of `x` to `missing`, you get an error, in the same way you would get an error if you tried `x[3] = "a string"`.

If you want an array to contain both the type `Missing` and the type `Float64`, then you need to specify up front that the elements of the array can be of type `Missing` or type `Float64`. In Julia v0.6 (which you specify in the question), you can do this via `missings`, which is located in the Missings.jl package, e.g.:

```
julia> x = missings(Float64, 2)
2-element Array{Union{Float64, Missings.Missing},1}:
 missing
 missing

julia> x[1] = 0.0
0.0

julia> x
2-element Array{Union{Float64, Missings.Missing},1}:
 0.0     
  missing
```

In v1.0, the core functionality related to `missing` was moved into `Base`, so instead you would need:

```
julia> Array{Union{Float64,Missing}}(missing, 2)
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
 missing
 missing
```

which is admittedly a little cumbersome. However, the `missings` syntax from v0.6 is still available for v1.0 in Missings.jl. It's just that many people may choose not to bother with this since the type `Missing` itself has moved to `Base`, so you don't *need* Missings.jl, unlike v0.6.

If you already have a pre-existing `Array{Float64}` and want to mark some of the elements as `missing`, then (as far as I know) you will need to re-construct the array. For example, in both v0.6 and v1.0 you could use:

```
julia> x = randn(2)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.642867
 -1.17995 

julia> y = convert(Vector{Union{Missing,Float64}}, x)
2-element Array{Union{Float64, Missings.Missing},1}:
 -0.642867
 -1.17995 

julia> y[2] = missing
missing
```

Note that `missing` is typically envisaged to be used in datatypes like `DataFrames`, where a lot of this stuff happens automatically for you, and so you don't have to waste time typing out so many `Union`s. This might be one reason why the syntax is a little verbose when working with regular arrays like you are.

One final point: you could of course explicitly construct your arrays to accept any type, e.g. `x = Any[1.0, 2.0] ; x[1] = missing`. The downside is that now the compiler cannot generate type-efficient code for working with `x` and so you will lose the speed benefits of working in Julia.

Comment: One alternative is `zeros(Union{Float64,Missing}, 5)`, which is still quite verbose. I wonder why `missings` was removed. If, in the future, a simpler syntax becomes available for the `Union`, we may see something like `zeros(Float64?, 5)`.

Comment: @DNF Agreed that would be nice syntax - I feel like I've seen it proposed in an issue somewhere, maybe by you :-)

Comment: `missings` hasn't been removed, it has always lived in the package Missings.jl.

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat Ah, I didn't realize Missings.jl would continue to be maintained after the jump to v0.7. I thought all the functionality had been migrated to `Base`, but you're right, they've left some of it in the package. I'll adjust my answer to reflect this. Many thanks.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thanks, this is nice for addressing the main issue. I was asking particularly in the context of DataFrames, however I'm not sure if the missing aspect is taken fully into account. For example running x = zeros(5) , y = zeros(5), df = DataFrame(y = y, x = x). If you replace df[:x][2] = missing it will return the same conversion error.

Comment: @NoviceStat I did wonder why you had that `using DataFrames` at the top of your code... I think this question should remain as is since it is a useful resource for those working with arrays. Also, for the specific case of dataframes there is also a dedicated question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716412/how-do-i-insert-missing-values-to-my-dataframe-in-julia) with a good answer. If you don't find your answer there, let me know.