# How do I insert missing values to my dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

```
df3[10, :A] = missing
df3[15, :B] = missing
df3[15, :C] = missing
```

Even NA is not working.

I am getting an error

> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Missings.Missing to an object of type Int64
>   This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Int64(...),
>   since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
>   Stacktrace:
>    [1] setindex!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Missings.Missing, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:583
>    [2] insert_single_entry!(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Missings.Missing, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/jrun/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:361
>    [3] setindex!(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Missings.Missing, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/jrun/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:448
>    [4] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `allowmissing!` function.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1,2,3])
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 3     │

julia> df.a[1] = missing
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Missing to an object of type Int64

julia> allowmissing!(df)
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a      │
│     │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │
│ 2   │ 2      │
│ 3   │ 3      │

julia> df.a[1] = missing
missing

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a       │
│     │ Int64⍰  │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ missing │
│ 2   │ 2       │
│ 3   │ 3       │
```

You can see which columns in a `DataFrame` allow `missing` because they are highlighted with `⍰` after type name under column name.

You can also use `allowmissing` function to create a new `DataFrame`.

Both functions optionally accept columns that are to be converted.

Finally there is a `disallowmissing`/`disallowmissing!` pair that does the reverse (i.e. strips optional `Missing` union from `eltype` if a vector actually contains no missing values).

Comment: can you suggest me the source to learn these new changes in julia1.0 cuz these things i did not find in the documentation

Comment: In the documentation you can find it here: http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/latest/#API-1. Also there is a tutorial on DataFrames.jl here: https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial (the topic of your question is covered in Chapter 3 there).